# How to migrate SQL Data into new Microsoft access Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

We have a 3gb file of data from our propriartary CRM system which is using SQL as a database.

The CRM is not meeting our needs and we are thinking about moving to Microsoft access and building our own system from the start.

We were wondering if it is possible to easily migrate the SQL database into access?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not 3GB worth of data. If you already have sql server why not just use sql server. Moving from sql server to Access seems like a horrible idea to me.

Comment: The main volume of the data is that our current CRM software saves every email we send and receive on that persons record.Would we be able to do something with this in access?

Comment: What you are asking is a massively large topic. I would strongly recommend NOT using Access as your DBMS when you have sql server. This is like saying you would prefer to drive a Yugo when a Ferrari is sitting in the driveway.

Comment: Please do not confuse MS Access as a RAD with Jet / ACE back-end database. There is no reason why you should not have a SQL server database and an MS Access front-end.

Comment: Ok so i can use MS access to build the front end for our SQL database?

Comment: Yes you can.   And many people do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it has been a long time since I've had to use MS-Access (thankfully) but I'm not sure Access is suitable for databases of that size. In my opinion, it's best suited to small, desktop-type applications with few concurrent users.

To answer your question, I believe Access offers a data import feature(see under the `External Data` ribbon in 2013) - though I'd suspect it might balk at the idea of 3GB of data.  **Edit:** Actually [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/62f21765-b5a6-4727-9285-6662535cf40e/whats-the-software-limits-of-access-2013) suggests the max databsae size is 2GB

What might be more useful however, is its `Linked Table` feature. If I remember correctly this allows you to access data stored in SQL Server (or a similar RDBMS) which is more suited to large volumes of data through an Access front end - complete with pre-canned forms, queries, reports etc..

Comment: Thank you for this. I used Access once a long while back and will need to relearn it, i have some basic programming skills. Is this much of an undertaking or is this something i can learn in a few days? 

How realistic would it be to build a new system in access?

Comment: One of the key selling points of Access (IMO) is how quickly somebody can get to grips with it - though that comes with the caveat that it does not guarantee good design etc.there has to be some knowledge of RDBMS concepts there already. My question would be... with that much data, what have you got against SQL Server?

Comment: We're not very techincal so we dont know how to use our SQL database without using the CRM that we have which we arent happy with. What would be the best way to utilise the data from our SQL server in terms of building our own way of accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and fairly straight forward to move all of your data tables from SQL Server to Access; however, SQL Server is a much more robust database engine than Access.  I would highly recommend against that.  I have however had very good success using Access ([ADP project files](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-an-Access-project-89c48da0-55a4-45d4-9ee5-95f67383d4cb)) as a front for the interface and using SQL Server as the database back-end for simple to moderate complexity interfaces.  If you are not getting the performance you desire from your SQL Server, you might want to consider query performance tuning and looking into memory and hardware upgrades first.  I think you will get better and faster results from doing that.

Comment: I'm not amazingly technical myself, We are simply not happy with our current CRM and looking to build our own one, we got the impression we could do this with access and migrate our data into it?

Comment: Access forms and reports with VBA are fairly easy to learn quickly.  It does have its quirks though, be prepared to get stuck on some weird things that you would think should be easy.  LOL  Like I mentioned in my comment, my best results come from using SQL Server as the database engine by creating an ADP project.  ADP projects hold no data in the files... just connect to your SQL server and allow you to to create forms, reports, etc. based off SQL Server's database objects.  Trying to stuff that much data into an access database file would probably be a nightmare.

Comment: What would be the best platform or format to use to build my our frontend to connect to our existing SQL database if its something i need to teach myself?

Comment: You could use linked tables - so the data is stored in SQL Server and Access - via custom forms etc.. provides your front end. I'd say do some research on that (or just have a stab at it) and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: I don't know that I can tell you that.  Access has the benefits of being fairly easy to learn I believe, particularly if you have visual basic experience.  But it also requires every one of your users to have a client license for MS Access.  A .NET windows form application would be a good choice as well, however there quite a bit steeper learning curve if you have no experience, but it is a very handy skill to develop.

Comment: @amcdermott - I prefer the ADP project files over linked tables in general because it works natively with SQL Server objects.  You could use linked tables, but really you want linked "views".  If you do a join on two linked tables, access has to drag down both tables to do the join instead of letting SQL Server do the work.  It is possible, it just takes a bit of design consideration.

Comment: @BrianPressler I'll bow to your superior knowledge. As I said, it has been close to 10 years since I've used Access.

Comment: Some good information on ADP/Linked Tables here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adp/hot.  I think properly designed... you might get a little less overhead using linked tables... but you really have to think about what you are downloading to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to “link” Access to SQL server. That way you continue to use a robust data engine, but are free to use all the reporting and coding features of Access.

In this setup then Access simply becomes a “front end” to the existing SQL database.

And you do NOT want to use an ADP project in Access since they are depreciated.

The process is thus to create a blank standard database, and then use linked tables to SQL server. This will not only eliminate the need to import data (which is likely changing all the time).